# Should a property return the value that was written to it?

Tags: python, properties

For an object attribute, we can assume that it refers to that value that was successfully assigned to it.

```
myobj.attr = w
r = myobj.attr
assert r == w
```

Data properties are basically calculated attributes and they are used just like regular attributes. Is it OK to implement a property that violates the above mentioned assumption?

I have an opinion - no property, but `set_x(value)` and `get_x()` - but opinions do not count. Is there a rule, or a recommendation from a respected source for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a purely semantical POV, getter/setter pairs are just the equivalent of computed attributes for languages that dont support computed attributes, so I wouldn't expect a getter/setter pair (in the `myobj.get_attr()` / `myobj.set_attr(w)` form) to behave differently from a property.

If having a property that violates this assertion hurts your sensibility then you may want to use a "not exactly a setter" that will more "explicitely" transform the value, ie `myobj.update_attr_from(something_different)` (and eventually keep the property read-only).

But really there's no hard rule here, and even as a "best practice" it's debatable (iow mostly opinion based). If you go that way, a common use case for a binding property (a property with a setter) is to validate the value and raise some exception if validation fails, which is not what you'd expect from a plain property either.

Answer (score 1):

Properties can do anything they like.  There are no rules or recommendations to what properties can and should do.

If it makes sense *for your specific usecase* for `myobj.attr` to produce a different value than was assigned, then just do so.